# Having trouble targeting a DesignableView in a UITableViewCell upon tapping it in order to change

Tags: ios, spring, swift

and thanks in advance for taking the time to help.

Inside my CellForRowAtIndexPath, I have the following line:

`cell.timeView.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonDidPress:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`

and my selector function is:

```
func ButtonDidPress (sender: DesignableView!){
    let view:DesignableView = sender
    cell.timeView.shadowColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    table.reloadData()
}
```

and the error i get is:

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I'm thinking that perhaps one can't send a View as a selector (am I using the correct terminology?), but how else can I target that particular view in that cell?

**UPDATE:**

I also tried using gestureRecognizer instead:

```
 var tap = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector( "viewDidTap:"))
    cell.timeView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

and

```
func viewDidTap (sender: DesignableView!){
```

but I got the same error here.

Thanks!

Comment: Does DesignableView inherit from UIButton? Also, is timeView of type DesignableView? You may want to use a UITapGestureRecognizer instead if it inherits from UIView. I would then use a block or delegate to send it back to the view controller.

Comment: No DesignableView does not inherit from UIButton, the idea was that I want to target the view when that button gets pushed. I tried your suggestion but i still get the same error. My code example has been updated accordingly.

Comment: The sender is wrong for the gesture. It should be sender: UITapGestureRecognizer. Also make the gesture a tap. A UITapGestureRecognizer in other words.

Comment: Ok I've done this, but how do I target that particular view (which is in a custom cell) from the viewDidTap function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of strange things happening in your code. It seems you want to change the `shadowColor` property of `timeView` when a user touch it, right?

Two possible solutions are:

1. (This one is IMO the better one) Change `DesignableView` to inherit from `UIButton`. Then you can set:
   `timeView.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonDidPress:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`. Make sure you set it just once for each cell. Otherwise you will get multiple calls on one tap.
2. Use `UITapGestureRecognizer`, but you should put it in your `UITableViewCell` subclass, not to the view controller. Also, the sender in `viewDidTap` is not the view itself, but the recognizer. So the method will go like this:

   ```
   func viewDidTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

       let location = sender.locationInView(sender.view)

       if timeView.hitTest(location, withEvent: nil) == timeView {

           timeView.shadowColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
           // table.reloadData() - you don't need to reload the table
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I used the second option because I have 2 views per cell. I still have an issue though, how do I get each view tap to manipulate data in the footer cell (which has a DateTime picker)? The idea is that I select a view (which has a time displayed it in), and then the slider should open, after which selecting a new time will display in the view that I had previously selected.